# How to add UPI, google Pay and other payment methods in stripe with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, google-pay

How to add payment methods other than card in stripe in NodeJS using stripe checkout session.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Checkout Session, Google Pay is automatically available if:

1. You accept card payments
2. You have a card saved in your [Google Wallet](http://pay.google.com/)
3. You are in a country that supports Google Pay (for example [India doesn't support it](https://support.stripe.com/questions/supported-payment-methods-currencies-and-businesses-for-stripe-accounts-in-india))

For UPI, you would need to contact [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) to enable it in your account.

More generally, for other payment methods:

1. Enable the payment method(s) in your [Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/payment_methods)
2. Then, when creating a Checkout Session, set [`payment_method_types`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_method_types)